# To implement TextWatcher with RxJava Android

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new to RxJava, to learn few fundamentals I've created a small project wherein I am trying to observe my EditText for changes in the entered text and updating a TextView.

Here is the code:

These are the instance variables for my Observable and Observers respectively

```
private Observable<String> editTextObservable;
private Observer<String> textViewObserver;
```

I am using RxBinding and am subscribing to the text changes like this:
I am doing this in `onCreate()`

```
RxTextView.textChanges(etData).
            subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            editTextObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Throwable {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged subscribe: " + etData.getText().toString());
                    emitter.onNext(etData.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And I am updating my TextView like this:

```
textViewObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull String value) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onNext: ");
            tvResult.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");

        }
    };
```

When I run the app it does not gives me any error and I can see in the logs the `onTextChanged()` listener being called, but the call never goes to `subscribe()` method and I am not able to see any result in the TextView. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you allowed to use an extension library for observing the onTextChange event? There is a wrapper for all kinds of events from ui elements, which will provide an observable.

Comment: @HansWurst you mean RxBinding?

Comment: Yes, this is the library I mean.

Comment: @HansWurst I tried it with RxBinding but still I am not able to see the results. I have updated the question too

Answer (score 0):

Example for observe when text changed with RxBinding library:

```
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()   

val disposable = editText.textChanges()
                    .map(CharSequence::toString)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe {
                        tvResult.text = it
                    }
     compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

And don't forget call`compositeDisposable.clear()` when activity called onDestroy() or fragment called onDestroyView().